# Web spider/crawler in C# Windows.forms

Tags: c#, web-crawler

I have created a web crawler in VC#. The crawler indexes certain information from .nl sites by brute-forcing all of the possible .nl addresses, starting with http://aa.nl to (theoretically) http://zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.nl.

It works all right except that it takes incredibly long time only to go through the two-letter domains - aa, ab ... zz. I calculated how long it would take me to go through all of the domains in this fashion and I got about a thousand years.

I tried to accelerate this by threading but with 1300 threads running at the same time, WebClient just kept failing, making the resultant data file too inaccurate to be usable.

I do not have access to anything else that a 5Mb/s internet connection, E6300 Core2duo and 2GB of 533@667mhz RAM on Win7.

Does anybody have an idea what to do to make this work? Any idea will do.
Thank you

Comment: “WebClient just failed rendering the result way too inaccurate.” What?

Comment: I didn't read it after myself. What I meant to say was that WebClient which is supposed to fail only when given invalid URLs failed valid URLs as well.

Comment: I don't think bruteforcing all possible website addresses is how web crawlers are intended to work.

Comment: But what if your assignment is to harvest information from all .nl sites? Now that I think of it, even if I was given a list of sites, this would be a task way too hard for a home computer. It might not have to take a thousand years but maybe two.

Answer (score 4):

The [combinatorial explosion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion) makes this impossible to do (unless you can wait several months at the very least). What I would try instead is to contact [SIDN](https://www.sidn.nl/), who is the authority for the .nl TLD and ask them for the list.

Answer (score 2):

IMO such implementation of a web crawler is not appropriate

1. The number of pings you need to do for one crawl is ~ 10<sup>29</sup>
2. Say every ping takes 200ms
3. Time for processing 100 ms

Total time estimate 3*10<sup>4</sup>*10<sup>29</sup> ms ~ **3*10<sup>23</sup> years**. Please correct me if I am wrong.

If you want to take advantage of threading you need to have a dedicated core per each thread. Each thread will at least take 1+ MB of your memory.

Threading will not help you here, you will be able to hypotheoretically reduce the time to ~ **3*10<sup>20</sup> years**

Exceptions that you get are likely to be the result of the thread synchronization issues.

Comment: You don't need dedicated core for each thread when the thread waits for a response most of the time.

Comment: @svick that's true, good point. From the other hand time will be wasted on switching the thread context.

Comment: The time it takes to switch context is tiny when compared with the 200 ms wait you expect for every request.

Comment: @svick well I disagree here, let's see. A raw estimate, 10 µs for 1 switch; 1500 threads for this process; 100 threads for all other processes. In total: 16ms, which is 8% from 200ms per one ping. That is significant time.

Comment: I certainly didn't mean having 1500 threads. Something like 100 should be more than enough. And It's better to waste 16 ms than to waste the whole 200 ms.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP support in .Net has a maximum concurrent connections limit of around 8 by default I think (somewhere around that figure anyway)

If you create more HTTP requests many of them will be forced to wait for an available connection and as a result will time out long before they ever get one leading valid URIs to appear invalid.

Comment: By default, .Net limits the number of concurrent connections *to one host* to 2. The number of hosts you can be connected to at one time is not limited by default, though. See [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx) and [ServicePointManager.MaxServicePoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.maxservicepoints.aspx).